# Does Citrix support Passwordless Single Sign On with Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, citrix, password-less

I've been researching about Citrix's capabilities to integrate a passwordless Single Sign On solution.
My company actually uses Active Directory as a primary Identity provider, and Azure AD to access SaaS applications. I want to integrate Citrix so users can access their desktops without having to login again, using FIDO2 keys.
It seems obvious that Citrix supports passwordless SSO when reading their documentation. But Azure AD's documentation says the opposite.

> The following scenarios aren't supported : RDP, VIDO, and Citrix scenarios using a security key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-passwordless-security-key-windows

I don't know what to beleive anymore.
We use **Citrix XenApp 7.15 LTSR** for now, but we will migrate to **Citrix Workspace 19.12 LTSR**.
We use the **Azure AD premium P1** licence. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You are mixing 2 different things. Please, clarify, do your Windows 10 computers are Azure AD or AD joined? If it is Azure AD joined, why you need AD? What is your authentication flow?

Comment: We're actually using hybrid azure AD joined devices. I beleive identities are still stored inside Active Directory (for security purposes). Users log in their Windows session, then authenticate through Citrix to access a remote Desktop.

Comment: For now, users have to authenticate too many times. What we'd like to do is enable some passwordless login for the windows session (preferably FIDO) then SSO through Citrix so they don't have to authenticate again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry if I'm not clear enough (I'm just an intern and I'm trying to process all this information as well lol).

Comment: thank you for answers! I will try to answer your question but do not hesitate to ask for any precisions

Answer (score 0):

1. What documentation is saying about FIDO keys that you cannot use them for authentication during remote session (VDI, Citrix, RDP) but nothing stops you to use it for local Windows session start. You need just be sure that you start your session with synchronized account (user which is present in AD and Azure AD).
2. As you have hybrid join devices there is no problem with Azure AD SSO, should work from the start with Microsoft Edge in Windows 10 (for other browsers search for SSO WIA). Try to login to https://portal.office.com to check, if it does not ask for anything, everything is good.
3. Last step, you need to setup Azure AD as Federated Authentication Service in Citrix Workspace (https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace/workspace-federated-authentication.html , possibly you need Cloud Connectors also). It will be the same scenario as for SaaS application. Azure AD will identify Windows user with current open session and provide a token to Citrix Workspace. Next, Citrix Workspace will match users and provide token for authentication in VDA.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that's exactly the information I was looking for ! It helped me understand much better. We're gonna try to set up this solution in the next few days / weeks, I will let you know if it worked.